# I can't use the sDNA toolbox on ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

When I import the sDNA toolbox into ArcGIS 10.2, some tools can be used, but other tools can't be used, the question are showed as follow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Please don't use pictures of text in questions it is hard to read and impossible to index,

Comment: Arcmap 10.2 is quite old, is the version is sDNA compatible with that version?

Comment: Thanks，I solved this question， sDNA should be used in English version, when I set it successfully，it can run successfully.